# How to create event programmaticall in Facebook via Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I initiate this:

POST `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/official_events`

```json
{
    "name": "Get Started with Ticketing",
    "description": "This is the best place to buy your first ticket",
    "access_token": "...",
    "place_id": "106502519386806",
    "cover": {
        "source": "https://example.com/cover.jpg",
        "offset_x": 0,
        "offset_y": 0
    },
    "category": "FAMILY_EVENT",
    "timezone": "US/Pacific",
    "start_time": "2012-03-24 17:45:12",
    "roles": {
        "100070263981179": "admin"
    },
    "redirect_uri": "https://tikex.com",
    "client_id": "2773133082797983"
}
```

Got this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) The global id 100070263981179 is not allowed for this call",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "Aac0g7OMu88sF1bL_tCshCW"
    }
}
```

Why? `100070263981179` is the page ID of my page. You can look at here: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100070263981179